# How to search informix database for a column

Tags: sql, informix

I want to be able to search an Informix DB for a column. In the main table there is a cust_nbr column, that is then referenced in a unknown number of tables.

In Informix, is there a way to query the DB and get all the tables that use the cust_nbr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT tabname, colno, colname  
FROM systables a, syscolumns b 
WHERE a.tabid = b.tabid 
and colname = "cust_nbr"
ORDER BY colno;
```

I found this code in the same place and added the extra restriant with colname = cust_nbr.

This seems to have worked for me. i will verify it, but all signs look like it worked.

i found that in the [Using the Informix Catalogs](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/0305parker/0305parker.html) mentioned in the other post

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this type of thing from the [system catalog tables](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst27.htm), `sysreferences` in particular.  As taken from [Using the Informix System Catalog](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/zones/informix/library/techarticle/0305parker/0305parker.html):

```
SELECT a.tabname, constrname, d.tabname 
  FROM systables a, sysconstraints b, sysreferences c, 
       systables d 
 WHERE b.constrtype = 'R' 
   AND a.tabid = b.tabid 
   AND b.constrid = c.constrid 
   AND c.ptabid = d.tabid 
   AND a.tabname = ?;
```

Comment: So i was looking at the documentation when you posted this. Where do i put the column "cust_nbr"?

Comment: With some hard work, this could be made to identify foreign keys that contain a given column name (which could be the 16th column in each of the two 16-part indexes on the two tables; that's the hard work!), but it is indirect and not all uses of the column name need to be in such constraints anyway.  The direct selection from SysTables and SysColumns is much simpler.